# Why mkdir fails with recursive option set true?

Tags: php, mkdir

I run the following code:

```
mkdir('mnt/1',0777,true);
mkdir('mnt/a',0777);
```

Directory "a" is created, while directory "1" is not, page prints warning.

```
Warning: mkdir(): File exists in /home/bitrix/www/php_test.php on line 3
```

I have full permissions on directory mnt for user apache is running:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 bitrix bitrix   4096 Nov 28 10:10 mnt
```

PHP version - PHP 5.3.3. Apache version 2.2.15.

Any ideas, why mkdir fails with recursive option set to true?

**Update!**
Well I cleared the folder, made the following php-script and ran it again:

```
<?php
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        mkdir('mnt/1',0777,true);
        mkdir('mnt/2/',0777,true);
        mkdir('./mnt/3',0777,true);
        mkdir('./mnt/4/',0777,true);

        mkdir('mnt/a',0777);
        mkdir('mnt/b/',0777);
        mkdir('./mnt/c',0777);
        mkdir('./mnt/d/',0777);
?>
```

Here is the output:

```
Warning: mkdir(): File exists in /home/bitrix/www/php_test.php on line 3 
Warning: mkdir(): File exists in /home/bitrix/www/php_test.php on line 4 
Warning: mkdir(): File exists in /home/bitrix/www/php_test.php on line 5 
Warning: mkdir(): File exists in /home/bitrix/www/php_test.php on line 6
```

Here is the content of the folder mnt after script execution:

```
drwxr-xr-x  1 bitrix bitrix  4096 Nov 28  2012 .
drwxrwx--- 11 bitrix bitrix 12288 Nov 28 11:10 ..
drwxr-xr-x  1 bitrix bitrix     0 Nov 28  2012 a
drwxr-xr-x  1 bitrix bitrix     0 Nov 28  2012 b
drwxr-xr-x  1 bitrix bitrix     0 Nov 28  2012 c
drwxr-xr-x  1 bitrix bitrix     0 Nov 28  2012 d
```

I also tried absolute path for recursive mkdir - still no luck, while non-recursive mkdir works fine no matter how the path is set. What's wrong with recursive mkdir? I still have no ideas..

**Update!** Further investigation revealed that such things happen because mnt is a folder, mounted by command

```
mount -t cifs -o username=***user***,password=***password***,uid=bitrix,gid=bitrix,iocharset=utf8,codepage=866 //192.168.1.6/folder /home/bitrix/www/mnt
```

In all other directories recursive mkdir works fine, while in that directory only non-recursive mkdir works!

**Update!** As **femtoRgon** assumed mkdir, when run from script in the folder `mnt`, works fine both recursive and non-recursive. But still I can't figure out, why it fails, when run from /home/bitrix/www? I even tried mounting with options `file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775` - no luck. My OS = CentOS 6.3, if it matters..

Comment: Do you already have a directory `1` in `mnt`?

Comment: No. Neither 'a' nor '1' directories exist prior to script execution

Comment: What is the owner/group and permissions of the 'a' dir once it gets created?
Another idea is that recursive call *may* be trying to change permissions of 'mnt' dir, which apache user doesn't own.

Comment: Please submit all your code. Your warning comes from line 3 but you only show 2 lines of code.

Comment: Ah ha!  I wonder if a recursive mkdir would work if it didn't have to traverse the mount point there (such as if executed from within mnt, and `mkdir('a/b/', 0777, true)`).  At any rate, it's okay to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question), so please do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some googling, I found the answer on [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.is-dir.php#98338). It is all about `serverino` mount option. When I mounted folder with `noserverino` all problems were gone. Anyway thanks guys for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

You may try appending a slash character to your first parameter.

```
mkdir('./mnt/1/',0777,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the right ways of creating directory :

```
mkdir('/test1/test2', 0777, true);

mkdir("test1/test2",0777,true);
```

So your error is probably on some of the missing lines.. Not in the way that you create the directories.

For more details you can check here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php