# Why does mkdir not work without recursion set to true?

Tags: php, html, mysql, unix

I was fiddling with my code, trying to write some code that will take data(including pictures) uploaded from a form via POST which will then create a directory complete with its associated subdirectories to store the image.

While writing the code, i kept getting the error

```
Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory in C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\UniServer\www\AddItem.php on line 94
```

HOWEVER, when i set mkdir's resursion to true, mkdir suddenly works and the directory is created without any problems.

My Code:

```
if(isset($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']))
 {
 $numfile=count($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']);
{
    for($i=0;$i<$numfile;$i++)
    {
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i]))
        {
            //Conditionals for uploaded file
            $foldername=$_SESSION['UserId'];
            $cat=$_POST['category'];
            $sub=$_POST['subcat'];
            $itemname=$_POST['itemname'];
            $allowed_filetypes=array('.jpg','.gif','.bmp','.png');
            $max_filesize = 2097152; // Maximum filesize in BYTES (currently 2.0MB).
            $upload_path = 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\UniServer\www\images\\'.$foldername.'\\'.$cat.'\\'.$sub.'\\'.$itemname.'\\'; // The place the files will be uploaded to.
            //Checks if Folder for User exists
            //If not, A folder for the user is created to store the user's images
            if(!file_exists($upload_path))
            {
                $upload_path=mkdir($upload_path,0644,true);<-- This is the line
            }

            $filename = $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i]; // Get the name of the file (including file extension).
            $ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1); // Get the extension from the filename.

            // Check if the filetype is allowed, if not DIE and inform the user.
            if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
            {
                die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');
            }

            // Now check the filesize, if it is too large then DIE and inform the user.
            if(filesize($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i]) > $max_filesize)
            {
                die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');
            }

            // Check if we can upload to the specified path, if not DIE and inform the user.
            if(!is_writable($upload_path))
            {
                $errormsg="Image Upload Failed.";
            }

            if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i],"$upload_path" . $filename))
            {
                $errormsg= 'Your file upload was successful, view the file <a href="' . $upload_path . $filename . '" title="Your File">here</a>'; // It worked.
            }

        }
    }
}




 }
   else{echo"Upload failed";}
```

While my code is working now that i've set recursion to true, i still DON't understand exactly WHY it is working, so i would really appreciate it if someone could explain why exactly my code is working.

The closest i've come is with [Why mkdir fails with recursive option set true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13599046/why-mkdir-fails-with-recursive-option-set-true)

Though i couldnt understand any of what was said in the link.

Thanks!

Comment: Not entirely sure just yet, but you are using sessions. Is `session_start();` inside and at the top of your code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why mkdir fails with recursive option set true?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13599046/why-mkdir-fails-with-recursive-option-set-true)

Comment: Yep, session_start(); is at the top of my code. I've just posted a chunk of my code that works with mkdir, namely the part that deals with uploading and storing the images.

Comment: can you check if the line `$upload_path = 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\UniServer\www\images\\'.$foldername.'\\'.$cat.'\\'.$sub.'\\'.$itemname.'\\';` is correct. can you echo the output of `$upload_path`

Comment: Mount your folder with `noserverino`.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13599046/why-mkdir-fails-with-recursive-option-set-true

Comment: @Ken I noticed you have 2 backslashes at the end of C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\UniServer\www\images\\ . Try taking that last one out as well as all other \\ to only 1.

Comment: @bansi

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\UniServer\www\images\5\Test2\abc\qwerty\

Comment: @Fred With the 2 backslashes, i get the error Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory in C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\UniServer\www\AddItem.php on line 94 . After removing one backslash however, i get the error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '\' (T_NS_SEPARATOR)

Comment: @Ken Give this a try: `$upload_path = 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\UniServer\www\images\'.$foldername.'\'.$cat.'\'.$sub.'\'.$itemname.'\';` or is that what you tried?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui Hi Areeb, i've taken a look at that post prior to posting the question, but i couldn't understand what was being said on that page, nor did a google search turn up any helpful results. Could you explain what noserverino actually is and what it does?

Comment: @Ken Ah, the problem seems to be on that line.

Comment: if recursion is not set to true `mkrir` will fail if any of the directory before `$itemname` don't exists. `C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\UniServer\www\images\5\Test2\abc\qwerty\` will fail if directory `C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\UniServer\www\images\5\Test2\abc` don't exists

Comment: @Ken Try removing the first dot in `.$foldername.` as in `$foldername.` - Could be that concatenation shouldn't start with a dot, but subsequent others yes.

Comment: also try using forward slash for directory separator cleaner and portable `$upload_path = "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/UniServer/www/images/$foldername/$cat/$sub/$itemname/";`

Comment: @Ken May be a silly question but I'll ask it anyway. Is `UserId` in your form set to the same value? You may have named it to `userid` in lowercase, or other. Worth checking, since most of your `$_POST` are in lowercase.

Comment: @Ken Plus I'm starting to wonder if this `C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\UniServer\www\images` shouldn't contain double backslashes as in `C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\UniServer\\www\\images` as you do in your concatenates. **Note:** SO is not letting me add the 2 trailing backslashes at the end `images` for some reason.

Comment: @Fred the 2 trailing backslashes are so the mysql keeps one backslash at the end of so there would be one backslash after images as backslashes are used to escape the following characters.Therefore 2 backslashes are needed so that one backslash would show. ilalopoulos and ep0 has answer my question. Thanks for your replies though!

Comment: @Ken Ok, I'm glad you found your solution, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mkdir()` needs the recursive set to true since you ask it to create nested directories that do not exist, i.e.:

```
$upload_path = 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\UniServer\www\images\\'.$foldername.'\\'.$cat.'\\'.$sub.'\\'.$itemname.'\\';
```

So since the variable $`foldername` gets its value from the user session, if the user session change it changes. The same goes for the rest of the `$upload_path` parts, if something of them changes you have to create the whole path. Only the last part of the path (`$itemname`) can change without using the recursive option.

Answer (score 1):

It fails because it parses the path provided as argument and "changes" path to parent of new directory.

Try this (in a folder `test` with a subfolder `s`):

- `mkdir s/s2/s3` <- will fail because `s2` does not exist in `s`
- `mkdir s/s2` <- ok
- `mkdir s/s2/s3` <- ok

When calling with `recursive` set to `TRUE`, it does something different: splits the path as usual, but checks existence of each prefix.

Again in folder `test`:

- `mkdir -p s/s1/s2/s3/s4` will yield the following prefixes:

  - `s`
  - `s/s1`
  - `s/s1`
  - `s/s1/s2`
  - `s/s1/s2/s3`
  - `s/s1/s2/s3/s4`

Note: I've used `mkdir` under linux and `p` argument tells it to create parent directories if they do not exist (same as recursive).

Comment: Hi ep0 , Thanks for taking the time out to reply.As i can only accept one answer, i've upvoted your answer instead.Once again, thanks for your reply!